Creating DropDown with Dynamic Input from External Data Source for App Script Gmail Add On
I am struggling to get this method to work and the documentation is unclear to me. I implemented a new selectionInput of type MULTI_SELECT which shows up in my gmail app. I'm calling the getExternalDataSource() method which is then successfully (according to logs) triggering my callback function getConversations() when I attempt a query in the app by searching for a conversation, the multi-select input field shows a loading icon then returns nothing. My logs show that the function successfully authenticated with Slack and grabs a list of all conversations for the authenticated user. The issue I'm certain is what my getConversations function is returning the object. The documentation just says that a SelectionInput object should be returned, but provides no specifics beyond that.
function onGmailMessageOpen(e) {
  // Activate temporary Gmail scopes, in this case to allow
  // message metadata to be read.
  var accessToken = e.gmail.accessToken;
  GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);


var onGmailOpenCard = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .setHeader(CardService.newCardHeader()
          .setTitle('Send Gmail to Slack Settings'))
      // main settings selection Card for Gmail to Slack
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
        // create workspace selection widget
        .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput()
          .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
          .setTitle("Select Workspace")
          .setFieldName("workspace_single_dropdown")
          .addItem(getTeamInfo().name, getTeamInfo().name, true)
          .addItem("Add New Workspace", "new_workspace", false)
            )
        // create channel and DM selection widget
        .addWidget(CardService.newSelectionInput()
          .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.MULTI_SELECT)
          .setTitle("Search channels and people")
          .setFieldName("people_multi_select")
          // .addMultiSelectItem("Contact 3", "contact-3", false,
          //   "https://www.gstatic.com/images/branding/product/2x/contacts_48dp.png",
          //   "Contact three description")
          .setMultiSelectMaxSelectedItems(5)
          .setMultiSelectMinQueryLength(3)
          .setExternalDataSource(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("getConversations")) 
            )


Callback Function getConversations
function getConversations(e) {
  Logger.log('getConversations function started');  // Log start of function
  
  var slackAccessToken = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN');
  var url = "https://slack.com/api/conversations.list";
    
  var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + slackAccessToken,
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var query = "?types=public_channel,private_channel,mpim";  // Request DMs and group DMs
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + query, params);
  Logger.log('Response received from Slack API');  // Log response receipt

  var conversations = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  
  if (conversations.ok) {
    Logger.log('Conversations data is OK');
    
    let selectionInput = CardService.newSelectionInput()
      .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.MULTI_SELECT)
      .setFieldName('people_multi_select')
      .setTitle('Search channels and people')
      .setMultiSelectMaxSelectedItems(5)
      .setMultiSelectMinQueryLength(3);
    
    // Iterate over the channels and add them to the multi-select input
    conversations.channels.forEach(function(channel) {
      Logger.log('Processing channel: ' + channel.name_normalized + ', ID: ' + channel.id);

      try {
        // Add item to the multi-select input
        selectionInput.addMultiSelectItem(
          String(channel.name_normalized),  // Channel name
          String(channel.id),               // Channel ID
          false,                            // Not pre-selected
          "https://via.placeholder.com/48",  // Placeholder icon
          "Channel ID: " + String(channel.id)  // Description
        );
        Logger.log('Successfully added channel: ' + channel.name_normalized);
      } catch (error) {
        Logger.log('Error adding channel: ' + channel.name_normalized + '. Error: ' + error.message);
      }
    });

    Logger.log('Total channels processed: ' + conversations.channels.length);

    // Return the card with the updated multi-select input
    var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
        .addSection(CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(selectionInput))
        .build();

    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
          .setNavigation(CardService.newNavigation().updateCard(card))
          .build();
  } else {
    Logger.log("Error fetching conversations: " + conversations.error);
    return null;
  }
}

I expect to have a drop down with channels available for selection as shown in this first screenshot from another app, not mine: example of desired behavior. Instead I get a loading icon indicating a query is being done (and logs indicate getConversations was triggered, but nothing is returned in a dropdown: example of current undesired behavior
